# python pandas conditional count across columns

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, dataframe, vectorization

I have a dataframe (called panel[xyz]) containing only 1, 0 and -1. The dimensions are: rows 0:10 and columns a:j.

I would like to create another dataframe (df) which has the same vertical axis, but only 3 columns:
    col_1 = count all non-zero values (1s and -1s)
    col_2 = count all 1s
    col_3 = count all -1s

I found this in searching SO:

```html
df[col_1] = (pan[xyz]['a','b','c','d','e'] > 0).count(axis=1)
```

...and have tried many different iterations, but I cannot get the conditional (>0) to distinguish between the different values in pan[xyz]. The count is always = 5.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit:

pan[xyz] =

```html
. 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f' 'g' 'h' 'i' 'j'
0 1 0 0 -1 0 0 -1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 -1
2 1 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0
3 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
4 0 0 0 1 0 0 -1 0 0 -1
```

df should be =

```html
. col_1 col_2 col_3
0 4 2 2
1 3 2 1
2 2 1 1
3 2 1 1
4 3 1 2
```

But this is what i get for col_1 :

```html
df = (panel[xyz] > 0).count(axis=1)

df
Out[129]: 
0    10
1    10
2    10
3    10
4    10
dtype: int6
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm just doing this with a flat dataframe but it's the same for panel.  You can do one of two ways.  The first way is what you did, just change the `count()` to `sum()`:

```
( df > 0 ).sum(axis=1)
```

The underlying structure is boolean and True and False both get counted, whereas if you sum them it is interpreted more like you were expecting (0/1).

But a more standard way to do it would be like this:

```
df[ df > 0 ].count(axis=1)
```

While the former method was based on a dataframe of booleans, the latter looks like this:

```
df[ df > 0 ]

    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j
0   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   1 NaN
1 NaN   1 NaN NaN NaN   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   1 NaN NaN
4 NaN NaN NaN   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

In this case it doesn't really matter which method you use, but in general the latter is going to be better, because you can do more with it.  For example, with the former method (which has binary outcomes by design), all you can really do is count, but in the latter method you can count, sum, multiply, etc.

The potential usefulness of this may be more obvious for the case of `df != 0`, where there are more than two possible values:

```
df[ df != 0 ]

    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j
0   1 NaN NaN  -1 NaN NaN  -1 NaN   1 NaN
1 NaN   1 NaN NaN NaN   1 NaN NaN NaN  -1
2   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN  -1 NaN NaN NaN NaN
3 NaN  -1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   1 NaN NaN
4 NaN NaN NaN   1 NaN NaN  -1 NaN NaN  -1
```

Comment: Thanks John, this is exactly what I needed to understand. Great explanation.